# Tailwind-css snap random initial position on refresh

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I use snap-y from tailwind-css to create snap effect on page blocks. Everything works well at local. But when I deployed it on vercel, a random block would be shown everytime I refresh the page. There are 2 blocks in total, so 1 of them will be shown each time. You can view the effect here on the deployed website: https://fpcc.vercel.app/

The code is the following:

```
<div class="snap-y h-screen w-screen overflow-scroll">
    <div class="snap-start shirnk-0 relative">
      <img src="./new/header.png" class="w-full"></img>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{style:{ color: "rgb(236,236,236)", position:"absolute", width:"10rem", height:"10rem", top:"55%", left:"25%"}}}>
        <div >
          <TbChevronsDown class="animate-bounce"/>
        </div>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </div>
    <div id="cursor-halo" class="snap-end shrink-0 bg-black w-full">
      <img src="./new/transition.png" class="object-cover w-full js-show-on-scroll"></img>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="./new/main-bg-1-rebel-cause.gif" class="object-cover w-full"></img>
      <Link href="https://mobile.twitter.com/FruitpunkCC_nft">
          <AiFillTwitterCircle class="cursor-pointer fixed w-20 h-20 top-1/3 right-0 z-10"/>
      </Link>
    </div>
    <img src="./new/main-bg-2-eternity.gif" class="object-cover w-full "></img>
    <div class="relative flex justify-center">
      <img src="./new/main-bg-3-team-cards.jpg" class="object-cover w-full"></img>
        <img src="./new/tc_left_btn.png" class="shadow-xl dark:shadow-gray-800 cursor-pointer absolute mt-40 w-30 h-60 left-10" onClick={onChangeTMCardLeft}></img>
        <img src={"".concat("./new/team-card-",curTeamMember,".png")} class="absolute max-w-4xl h-auto z-0"></img>
        <img src="./new/tc_right_btn.png" class="cursor-pointer absolute mt-40 w-30 h-60 right-10" onClick={onChangeTMCardRight}></img>
    </div>
    <img src="./new/footnote.png" class="object-cover w-full"></img>
  </div>
```

Thanks!